# jQuery(window).load(function($) still gives Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am having issues using jquery in my Wordpress site. After reading this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12258282/typeerror-is-not-a-function-wordpress), I thought I'd be able to solve my issue, but this is not the case.

This is what I have tried, but I still get the Type Error:

```
jQuery(window).load(function($)
{
    // auto panning
    PanPicture = function () {
        $(".wrap").show();
        $(".wrap").children("#panimg").show();
        $(".wrap").children("#panimg").animate({
            "left": "-800px"
        }, 20000);
        $(".wrap").children("#panimg").animate({
            "left": "0px"
        }, 20000);
        // refill the animation queue after animations done
        $(".wrap").children("#panimg").queue(

        function () {
            PanPicture();
            $(".wrap").children("#panimg").dequeue();
        });
    };
    //setTimeout( function() { PanPicture(); }, 1000 );
    //$(".wrap").children("#panimg").load(function() { PanPicture(); });
    PanPicture();
});
```

The console gives me this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
PanPicture @ jd_autopan.js?ver=4.4.2:5
(anonymous function) @ jd_autopan.js?ver=4.4.2:23
m.event.dispatch @ jquery.js?ver=1.11.3:4r.handle @ jquery.js?ver=1.11.3:4
```

Comment: well  yeah, that first argument is an event object.. don't confuse $(document).ready with $(somedomnode).load

Answer (score 5):

Try this and make sure your script is loaded **after** jquery (if you're using `wp_enqueue_script` to add your script, pass `array('jquery')` as 3rd param)

```
jQuery(document).ready(
function ($)
{
    //blah blah
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(window).on("load", function() {
        console.log("Your function will triggered");
    });
});
```