# Uncaught Type Error - jQuery - WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I came across this error while using jQuery with WordPress and followed [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12258282/typeerror-is-not-a-function-wordpress) answer to resolve. But, the error persists.

```
Error : Uncaught TypeError: $el.appear is not a function
at PluginAnimate.build (theme.js:66)
at PluginAnimate.initialize (theme.js:38)
at PluginAnimate (theme.js:18)

 <script>
 jQuery.noConflict();
 </script>
```

Few lines from theme.js which has errors

```
$(window).afterResize(function() {
$headerContainer.css('min-height', $header.height());
});

$el.appear(function() {
delay = ($el.attr('data-appear-animation-delay') ? 
$el.attr('data-appear-animation-delay') : self.options.delay);

if (delay > 1) {
$el.css('animation-delay', delay + 'ms');
}

$el.addClass($el.attr('data-appear-animation'));
setTimeout(function() {
$el.addClass('appear-animation-visible');
}, delay);
},
```

Code continues....

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: From what I can tell from a google search, jQuery.appear is a plugin. Are you sure you have it installed? .appear is not a native jQuery function.

Comment: `(function (jQuery) {
    window.$ = jQuery.noConflict();
})(jQuery);`

Comment: @Thiatt Thank you. That was helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Thiatt, I missed to include jQuery Appear Plugin.