# Can't get jQuery find if in ViewPort to work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know the question of how to find if an element is visible in the viewport using jQuery has already been answered, but I'm having trouble getting it to work for me. The jQuery code that I'm using based on other answers is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$(window).scroll(function() {
var top_of_element = $(".basic-box1").offset().top;
var bottom_of_element = $(".basic-box1").offset().top + $(".basic-box1").outerHeight();
var bottom_of_screen = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
var top_of_screen = $(window).scrollTop();

if((bottom_of_screen > top_of_element) && (top_of_screen < bottom_of_element)){
   $('.basic-box1').fadeIn();
}
else {
   $('.basic-box1').fadeOut();
}  
});
});
```

Html:

```
<div class="basic-box1"> 
  <p class="how-p1">Text text text</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.basic-box1 {
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  border: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  padding: 40px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 700px;
  margin-top: 800px;
}
```

I feel like I must be missing something obvious. I've tried just about everything I know and can't get it to work. Any help would be much appreciated. 
If it would help to see it on my site it's at http://www.claywhaley.com

Comment: what is #element ?

Comment: ok so what other issue u are facing ?

Comment: Well I have it just like that on my site but it doesn't give any effect. I'm trying to create a fade in effect as the box comes into the viewport but it's not working.

Comment: is there any error on console log ?

Comment: ok your website console has an error $ is not a function coz of wordpress please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12258282/typeerror-is-not-a-function-wordpress

Comment: Looks like that fixed the problem, now I just need to mess around with it to get it working smoothly. I guess I should hide basic-box1 with display: none; or visibility: hidden; in the css? I'll experiment but I thought I'd ask. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your website console has an error `$ is not a function` coz of wordpress. Please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12258282/typeerror-is-not-a-function-wordpress)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have it working but it looks like the box is fading in before it's actually in the viewport. When I load the screen where the box is, it's hidden, then I scroll and it fades in. So I know it's working, but it's just happening before I scroll down to the spot where the box is. Any thoughts on how to fix this? It's the same code as above.

Comment: you can see it at http://www.claywhaley.com/. It's the first box after "how it works"

Comment: Alright, I know I keep commenting but it's just in case someone ever has the same problem as me. I fixed it by putting var top_of_element = ($(".basic-box1").offset().top; - 400);  I think the margins and/or fixed header was throwing off the position so the - 400 fixed it.

Comment: take the header height dynamically `var top_of_element = ($(".basic-box1").offset().top; - $("header").height());`