# $ is not a function after wordpress 5.3 update

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I've been using the code below and it has worked fine for years, but updating to wordpress 5.3 it throws me the error: $ is not a function.

Is there something that has depreciated?

```
<script>$("img").on('click',function(){

   var hello = $(this).attr('data-id');
   $('.hideDivs').hide();
   $('#'+hello).show();
});
</script>

<script>
  $("img").on('click',function(){
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: ($('#about-caje').offset().top)
},500);
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: That usually means that jQuery isn't being included. Have you tried disabling all your plugins?  Switched to a different theme?

Comment: This may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20934305/3533413

Comment: It was my understanding wordpress always includes jQuery, has this changed?

Comment: jQuery comes bundled with WordPress, yes, but it's not loaded unless your theme and/or a plugin explicitely requires it. Hence the suggestions/questions from previous commenters here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be because of this:
https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/48568

If so, then wrapping your code, like in the answer linked by Spencer Stewart might help.

```
<script> 
jQuery(function($) {

YOUR CODE GOES HERE

});
</script>
```