# $ is not a function - how to solve it

Tags: wordpress, function, typeerror

I recently updated all the plugins and themes in WordPress. After the update, I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    at (index):2151
(anonymous) @ (index):2151

var $slid = $('#wp_posts_carousel-2 .owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: $ is not a function when calling jQuery function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343714/typeerror-is-not-a-function-when-calling-jquery-function)

Comment: Another: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12258282/typeerror-is-not-a-function-wordpress